# Sorting a large number of files into a hierarchical tree structure in java

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, data-structures

I have a large number of files (a couple thousand XML files), and I need to write a GUI in java which sorts these files into a tree structure based on "Category" elements within the XML data of each file. This program may be run multiple times a day, and small changes/additions may be made to these files daily as well.

**How can I save this sorted structure in a way that will minimize load time during subsequent executions of the application?** This program will - unfortunately - be working with files on a USB harddrive, so therefore I am trying to avoid parsing each XML document every time the application is run in order to build this tree.

For example, each XML file may have multiple attributes (ie. "Person" with a value of "Fred", and "Organization" with a value of "Google"), and I would like to allow the user to select groups of files based on these category values within the GUI.

Thank you in advance for any and all assistance =)

Comment: What about you kept a separate index alongside the files? Each time a xml file is updated, so should the index. And loading the sorted tree structure would need to load just the index file.

Comment: Alright, so If I understand you, I should create a seperate index file which lists all of the XML documents along with the categories which they have been found to belong to? Maybe also throw in the date last modified attribute for each in order to see which may have been modified and require re-parsing? This will greatly reduce load time?

Comment: Or to make your life even easier, install a SQL database engine and import the xmls into the database (you can do it based on a schema). Then the database will take care about data modification tracking and index building. For displaying the tree, all it would then take is a simple SELECT statement.

Comment: Would I be importing *references* to the XML files into the SQL database? Or the files themselves? If I am importing the files themselves, would I need to do this manually each time a new file is created that needs to be categorized? This program will be run by someone who is not exactly "Computer Savvy", so I would like to keep the operation as simple and hidden as possible.

Comment: You would be importing the DATA from the XML files. You don't need to do it manually... you could write a small utility task to be run each time a certain folder is modified. That task would take the modified file, parse it, and reflect the changes to the database. Depending on the SQL engine, the parsing can be done by the SQL engine itself. So the task wouldjust detect the changes in a folder and pass the modified file to the SQL engine for parsing.

Comment: Sounds fantastic; Would you mind suggesting an SQL engine which is optimal for this task? And could you also post an answer to the question so that I can mark it as solved? ;) Thanks!

Comment: Wait a minute... be careful. How often do these XML files change?

Comment: @durron597 These files will hardly ever be *modified*, but new files will be added maybe once or twice a day.

Comment: Okay, you say these files are on a USB hard drive... are you guaranteed to have access to a central server? Or is the application going to be stored on the hard drive with the files? What if I'm on a plane with my laptop and the USB drive. Will I need to run this program?

Comment: @durron597 I should have been more specific about the context of this project; The computer that all of this will run on is a stationary desktop computer. The files are located on an attached USB drive which will never be disconnected. Ideally, I would have the program run off of the computers local disk, and if I implement an SQL database, it would also be located on this disk. There will be no relocation or remote access involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what you need to do.

1. Create a SQL database that will store BOTH the file names and the relevant XML tree structure data.

   - [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) Is a good, free option.
2. When the application starts up, have it scan the directory for file names and compare with the database's list of file names.

   - Any names that are not indexed should be parsed and added to the database.
   - Spawn a new thread to go through these unindexed files and process them, so the user doesn't see any lag.
3. Include a button on the application called "Recreate Cache".

   - Leave a warning "Only press this button when a file has changed" or something
   - Let the user tell your application when an old file has changed, since it almost never happens.

Alternatively to options 2/3, you could do this:

1. Create a Daemon task

   - This would be a separate program that keeps the database maintained
   - Have it watch for changes to the XML directory and update the database appropriately.
   - It could also periodically check for changes to the other files, once a day at 2 AM maybe.

Comment: @araisbec: I don't know if you saw the first version of my answer, but this version is better so make sure to reload the edit

Comment: I got the edit; This sounds good to me. Your suggestion is right about the daemon task is right in line with what Jakob Zaverka suggested. I am currently reading up on XPath expressions for use with MySQL, and I will be implementing this solution. Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you just also save the "last edited" date in the database and check the files for their last edit? If it's different, reload them into the database, otherwise not? This would prevent the user from having to press the reload button.

Comment: Might I suggest that in this case, especially as we were talking about USB drives and simple databases, that [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is also a good alternative? It's often under-rated, and highly useful for use cases like this where a full-blown DBMS (such as MySQL) is not really needed.

Comment: I will look into SQLite, thank you for the suggestion.

Also, I just want to add something I learned; Apparently, with the new Java.nio library included in Java 7, you no longer need to poll a folder constantly to detect changes. There is now a Watch Service API which notifies you of changes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't read and parse every file again and again each time they must be displayed. You can store the data from the XML files in some other format, that allow for fast and efficient reads. The format perfect for that is a relational database.

So here is what you need to do:

1. Install a SQL engine. I am no expert in licencing, but MySQL should achieve what you need and it's for free. Create a table with comlumns that matches the structure of your XML files.
2. Write a system service that watches for changes on file system (you can use FileSystemWatcher from the .NET). You can use Java instead of C#, but then you would have to implement it by periodical polls.
3. Each time a change occurs, the services takes the file and sends it to the SQL database. There you can easily parse the file by SELECT ExtractValue(xml). Once you get the data, you commit them to the table as a insert (new files) or update (edited files).
4. Each time you need to load the files into the tree, you run a simple SELECT statement on the database, returning the data in structure you need.

Comment: This essentially what I will be doing, @durron597 just beat you to the answer. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction though.